# I've used up my close votes, but I can still "flag" questions

Tags: discussion

I've somewhat recently picked up the banner of sitting in the review section when it's slow with the tags for which I am active.

A couple of times, I've run out of close votes during a day. Today, discovered that instead of voting to close a question, I could also "flag" the question under the same reason.

Is there a different process involved for flagging and voting to close?

I'd rather reduce work of those reviewers involved, so if using my "extra" 20-ish flags causes work for people, I'd rather save these for egregious issues rather than use these as an extension of my close votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. Even though they still appear in the flag menu for you, attempting to use them will automatically convert it into a close vote, and attempting to submit will still give you an error that you've run out of close votes for the day. It will *not* start using your flag count.

As a user with close voting privileges, it is not possible for you to create a flag for the close reasons.